# Как mysql update выполнить через время после запроса?

Tags: php, mysql

у меня есть запрос который должен по истечению минуты только выполнять update 
а оно сразу выполняет игнорируя time

```
$this->db->query("
        update colban
        set `go` = `go` -1
         where id = '".(int)$this->url[450]."' 
        < ".( time()-60*1 )); 
    }
```

Comment: может events поможет

Comment: Вы абсолютно уверены, что это именно, чего вам хочется? Может вы опишите для чего вам понадобилось такое поведение и поищем более правильные альтернативы?

Answer (score 1):

Как уже многие сказали, тебе это не нужно.

Причина этого вопроса - в непонимании элементарных основ баз данных.

#### Проверять значение должен не тот скрипт, который записывает данные, а тот, который читает.

То есть в данном случае мы не определенное значение записываем в БД в нужное время, а записываем **желаемое время изменения значения.**

А все читающие скрипты будут считывать это время и сравнивать с текущим. Если больше - то значение изменилось. Очень просто, и не требует никаких костылей из других ответов. Так работают базы данных во всем мире.

Comment: читает select, тоесть он должен сначала считать и если значение равно нужному или 0 то оно потом делает запрос на update// а как реализовать в запись то что бы все верно было

Answer (score 0):

1. Условие WHERE в SQL-запросе всего лишь задает условие, при соблюдении которого будет обновлена запись. Оно никаким образом не управляет временем исполнения запроса.
2. Откуда вы вообще взяли подобный синтаксис?
3. Составление запроса таким образом - крайне плохая практика. Изучите как работает [mysqli_stms_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
4. Для того, чтобы отложить выполнение какой либо команды есть куча вариантов, но все они в той или иной мере являются костылями.

Например:

- Можно создать JOB в mysql, который будет переодически читать таблицу очереди (в которую вы будете заносить задания на update) и выполнять те, которые старше минуты
- Можно тупо притормозить выполнение скрипта оператором `sleep(60)`
- Можно по `curl` (с обрывом сессии) вызывать скрипт, который будет выполнять update через минуту
- Можно сохранять задачи на update в файл(или таблицу БД) и по крону запускать обработку (почти то-же самое, что и первый вариант)
- Можно помудрить с `events`
- Можно посмотреть на [FPM](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.fpm.php) и его функцию [fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php)
- И т.д. и т.п.

Comment: [функция mysqli_bind_param помечена УСТАРЕВШЕЙ начиная с версии PHP 5.3.0 и была УДАЛЕНА в версии PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-bind-param.php)

Comment: @Alex ну да, промахнулся немного. Конечно же mysqli_stms_bind_param

Comment: ну задача состоит в том что после запроса по ссылке, будет происходит отсчет определенного времени а потом уже выполняться запрос в бд с отчетом минуты например

Comment: ну почему же? в вопросе не указана версия php, поэтому просто стоит напомнить участнику об этом.

Comment: @kursof Вы хотите, чтобы условие на выполнение через опред. время соблюдалось в самом запросе mysql ? почему бы не воспользоваться средствами php ( `sleep()` ) ?

Comment: @Alex будьте добры покажите пример такого запроса( sleep() )

Comment: @Alex кода там есть несколько дней

Comment: @Alex а < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY можно ли использовать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Вариант 1 - используйте функцию mysql [SLEEP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep), команда `DO SLEEP(60);`

   Пример запроса mysql:
   `DO SLEEP(60);`
   `UPDATE ...`
   *можно использовать `SELECT SLEEP(60)`, но в данном случае нужно учитывать, что на выходе всегда будет 0 или 1.*
2. Вариант 2 - используйте функцию php [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php).

   Пример:
   `SLEEP(60);`
   `$this->db->query("...");`

Оба варианта откладывают выполнение на N секунд.

---

Данные функции не стоит использовать если Вы выполняете следующий запрос только после получения результатов выполнения предыдущего, т.к., например, последовательный вызов 2-х запросов приведет к простою 2*N секунд.

Comment: а что насчет производительности? жрать будет или нет если это не один запрос, а много и от разых

Comment: @kursof не тестировал на многих и от разных, но по факту  функции всего лишь откладывают выполнение и на производительности их использование в Вашем случае сказаться не должно.

Comment: ваш вариант хорошо, но он груз страницу ровно 60 секунд, а потом выполняет, так не подойдет(

Comment: Очень печально, что на этом сайте плюсуют вредные ответы на бессмысленные вопросы.

Comment: @Ипатьев ну вопрос то интересный) а в чем же вредность ответа?

Comment: @Ипатьев :) меня попросили показать вариант со sleep я и показал) Что касается выводов, то после уточнения от автора о множестве запросов, я не могу сказать, что это подходящий ответ(дописал в ответе), но согласиться о его вреде не могу, т.к. в вопросе не стоит условие о множестве запросов и запрос по факту выполнится после `sleep`. Таким образом он отвечает условию задачи `должен по истечению минуты только выполнять update`.